# How is a parallel scan performed on an array with more elements than threads per block?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda

I have seen many implementations of parallel scan; the two main ones are Hillis & Steel and blelloch scan. Though all the implementations I have seen work within shared memory, memory only shared between threads in a block.

Are there any implementations of scan that work well over arrays that have more elements than threads per block, i.e. the array will not fit into shared memory?

This link mentions a scan implementation I see in all my searches, a Hillis Steele version, example 39-1 https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html.

Is the only option to do a segmented scan on sub arrays within the array and then do a "final scan" adding a magnitude value from the prior sub array to the next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With or without shared memory, CUDA kernels execute in chunks (threadblocks) that can execute in any order.  To take full advantage of the hardware, you must have multiple threadblocks in your kernel call, but this creates an uncertain execution order.

Because of this, a scan algorithm that works across a large array will necessarily have to work in threadblock-sized pieces (in some fashion).  If we have multiple threadblocks, then a given threadblock has no way of knowing whether other threadblocks have finished their work on adjacent data.  (Yes, there are contrived mechanisms to allow inter-threadblock communication, but these are fraught with difficulty and don't solve the problem on a large scale.)

The net effect of this is that algorithms like this generally imply a global sync of some sort, and the only safe-in-any-scenario global sync is the kernel launch.   Threadblocks can do a portion of their work independently, but when it comes time to stitch the work of threadblocks together, we must wait until step A is completed across all threadblocks before proceeding with step B.

Therefore I think you'll find that most *device-wide* scan algorithms, including the chapter 39 GPU Gems example you linked, as well as [thrust](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__prefixsums.html) and [cub](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/group___device_module.html) will launch multiple kernels to get this job done, since the kernel launch gives a convenient global sync.

Note that we can certainly devise a scan that has individual threadblocks that "work on more elements than threads per block", but this does not ultimately solve our problem (unless we use only 1 threadblock), because we must launch multiple threadblocks to take full advantage of the hardware, and multiple threadblocks in the general case introduces the global sync necessity.

The cub and thrust implementations I mentioned are both open-source template libraries, so you can certainly study the code there if you wish (not a trivial undertaking).  They do represent high-quality approaches designed and built by CUDA experts.  You can also at a high level study their behavior quite easily using:

```
nvprof --print-gpu-trace ./mycode
```

to get a quick read on how many kernels are being launched and what data transfers may be occurring, or you can use `nvvp`, the visual profiler, to study this.